# Oracle 11g - split columns into rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have sql result which looks like this

```
ID  |   ERROR_1 |   ERROR_2
1   |   '1'     |   '2'     
2   |   null    |   '2'     
3   |   '1'     |   '2'     
4   |   '1'     |   null
```

and I want to split each `ERROR_X` row to result like this:

```
ID  |   ERROR
1   |   '1'
1   |   '2'
2   |   '2'
3   |   '1'
3   |   '2'
4   |   '1'
```

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Query is similar to this:

```
SELECT h.id as ID,
CASE WHEN h.floor=1 THEN '1' END as ERROR_1,
CASE WHEN w.color='blue' THEN '2' END as ERROR_2,
FROM home h
LEFT JOIN window w ON w.id=h.window_id;
```

Currently I use UNIONS but cost of this query is huge (each query needs to select data from table where ID is of type string, do some joins and filter data). I want to try to query main table with string id only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your select query into WITH clause and unpivot this data.

```
WITH VDATA AS (
  SELECT 
    h.id as ID,
    CASE WHEN h.floor=1 THEN '1' END as ERROR_1,
    CASE WHEN w.color='blue' THEN '2' END as ERROR_2
FROM home h
LEFT JOIN window w ON w.id=h.window_id
) SELECT 
    ID,
    ERROR
  FROM VDATA
  UNPIVOT (error for errorid in (ERROR_1 as '1', ERROR_2 as '2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though you need to use `union all`:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN floor=1 THEN '1' END AS error
FROM   home
UNION ALL
SELECT window.id, CASE WHEN window.color='blue' THEN '2' END 
FROM   window
JOIN   home ON window.id = home.window_id
```

Comment: See my edit. Currently I use UNIONS but cost of this is too big.